# Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $a$, then it is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to prove that

if $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $a \in A$, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a constant $M>0$ and a neighborhood $N(a)$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in N(a)\cap A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition of continuous function, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in A\cap\left(a-\delta,a+\delta\right)$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<1$, hence $f(a)-1<f(x)<f(a)+1$ and $|f(x)|<\max\left\{|f(a)-1|,|f(a)+1|\right\}$. We can choose $N(a)=\left(a-\delta,a+\delta\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(a) \neq 0$, we can take $\varepsilon = |f(a)|/2 > 0$ in the definition of continuity. There is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$, $|f(x)-f(a)| \leq |f(a)|/2$. This last inequality can be rewritten as $$\frac{|f(a)|}{2} < f(x) < \frac{3|f(a)|}{2}.$$